# Correlation between BPMN event and trigger

Tags: bpmn

I have been reading BPMN 2.0 . Can some some one please tell me the difference between event and trigger and how do they both correlate from BPMN perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this question can be answered in two manners.

**Simplified manner**, where all secondary details are dropped.

*Event* is something that answers the question *WHAT happened?*
*Trigger* is something that answers the question *WHY it happened?*

**Qualified manner**, with all the required details.

Event is something that happens with the context of the process, which changes process state, data objects, process flow.
The main fundamental events of any process are:

1. Start event
2. End event
3. Intermediate event, i.e. something really significant

The first two determine if the process was stopped or still working.

Triggers are much more versatile entities, also called *Event Definitions*, and are designated to be *caught* by events, i.e. to activate them. They can be described as a set of conditions which, if true, fire some event. Triggers can be:

1. Message-triggers. They are executed when receiving the message.
2. Time-triggers. They are executed on time alarm.
3. Conditional triggers. They are fired when certain conditions are met.
4. Escalation triggers. They are fired when the process is escalated.
   and much much more

Exact set of available triggers depends on concrete BPMS and requires a separate solid article.